# Skype BOT C# Not Running Correctly

Tags: c#, bots, skype, skype4com

I am making a Skype bot in C# but I'm having a problem. It isn't reading my own commands, only the commands received by others.

When I add something like "!Resolve (username)" it makes the code all bugged up by bugged up i mean it just crashes the tool when i start it.

Could somebody please look and see if there are any major issues.

```
private Skype skype;
    private const string trigger = "!";
    private const string nick = "The OG Bot";
```

And this

```
private string ProcessCommand(string str)
    {
        string result;
        switch (str)
        {
            case "resolve":
                result = "Currently Not Working Will Fix Soon.";
                break;
            case "help":
                result = "Here are some commands you can run. \n !resolve \n !date \n !time \n !who \n !swag \n !ip";
                break;
            case "date":
                result = "Current Date is: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString();
                break;
            case "time":
                result = "Current Time is: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
                break;
            case "who":
                result = "This API was created by TehMerkMods";
                break;
            case "ip":
                result = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://icanhazip.com");
                break;
            case "swag":
                result = "(mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) (mm) ";
                break;
            default:
                result = "Sorry, I do not recognize your command";
                break;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

And last of all

```
private void skype_MessageStatus(ChatMessage msg, TChatMessageStatus status)
    {
        if (TChatMessageStatus.cmsRead == status)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (msg.Body.IndexOf(trigger) == 0 && TChatMessageStatus.cmsReceived == status)
        {
            string command = msg.Body.Remove(0, trigger.Length).ToLower();
            skype.SendMessage(msg.Sender.Handle, nick + " : " + ProcessCommand(command));
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean it "makes the code all bugged up"?  Please describe the behavior you are expecting and the behavior you are seeing.  We need details.

Comment: @Amy Well basically it doesn't grab the functions after that it just gives me a build error basically it cannot read my own commands what ever i do but reads other users sent commands just fine

Comment: Could you please post the error that you are receiving when it crashes?

Comment: You're getting a build error?  **What build error?**  When I said we need details, I meant that you need to provide us with details.  **Be specific, not vague.**

Answer (score 1):

You are only getting 'received', you need to get 'send' also

Example:

```
if (TChatMessageStatus.cmsReceived Or Status = TChatMessageStatus.cmsSent)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an if statement in the last section of code that is only looking for the TChatMessageStatus.cmsReceived.  This statement will never be true when you send a message because you don't receive your own messages.

As for the program crashing... you need to give more information.